# RelativeLayout not working properly Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the next problem: I use a lot the RelativeLayout, like the Android documentation is telling me to do. But, since few days, I don´t understand why, this is not working anymore:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my layout, very simple. So, according to this one, the textView should be BELOW the button, but, instead, it appears OVER the button!

[image: This is a picture of the result].

Сan anyone explain me what happens?

EDIT: The problem is not when I try to run it on a device, the problem comes when I see it on the graphical layout of the ADT Plugin for Eclipse...

Comment: Did you end your `RelativeLayout`, your code is working for me. `</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: your code is working well for me too.
did you end the relative layout tag as Asok said

Comment: Working fine close the relative layout tag.

Comment: Keep in mind that if your xml file has an error which doesn't allow it to build properly then it will show the last preview that was working properly.

Comment: The problem is not to run it on a device......The problems comes to see it on the graphical layout of the ADT plugin on Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I try this code it's working properly.

If your side not working properly Try to Clean build your project and then Run.

If still having problem then Try this

```
android:layout_below="@+id/boton"
```

remove above line with this

```
android:layout_below="@id/boton"
```

Because "+" create new reference to R.java file

This may be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try by removing the below line from your code
android:layout_marginTop="60dp"

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the `drawable` for the background, since I am not seeing an image in your preview.

Having this issue is giving you a `build error` so the preview doesn't show the layout in its current state (it reverts to the last sucessful build). Either remove that line and save to see the preview or check to make sure that you have an image in your `drawable`s folder titled "background"

Try this, without the drawable to check if it is working for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the '+' sign out of the TextView's `layout_below` attribute. The '+' tells it to deine a new id. Without the '+' it should refer to the existing one.

Comment: It'll works with or without the `+`, albeit the `+` shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to run it, and now, I know what´s the problem.

When running the app in a terminal, it is working properly, the problems comes when I try to see it on the graphical layout on the ADT plugin on Eclipse! Anyone with the same problem??

Answer (score -1):

Add `</RelativeLayout>` at the end of your relative layout to close it.